# User input stored in methods

Tags: c#

I'm having trouble with methods. So in one method I ask the user for first name and I want to store that String in another method, then have my main method call the method where the String is stored. But I'm having a trouble storing that string. I'm using this code:

```
static void GetStudentInformation()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Enter the student's first name: ");
    string firstName = Console.ReadLine();
}

static void PrintStudentDetails(string first)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0}", first);
}

public static void Main (string[] args){
    GetStudentInformation();
}
```

So once they enter the name, it should be stored in the details method then called upon in the main method. Thanks for helping me in advance.

Comment: also the GetStudent has multiple strings and a birth day it needs the user to input. so it can't be static string.

Answer (score 6):

```
static string GetStudentInformation()
{
     Console.WriteLine("Enter the student's first name: ");
     return Console.ReadLine();
}

static void PrintStudentDetails(string first)
{
     Console.WriteLine("{0}", first);
}

public static void Main (string[] args)
{
     string firstName = GetStudentInformation();
     PrintStudentDetails(firstName);
}
```

In case you need to retrieve more than 1 input from the user. You can return a list of strings (quick solution):

```
static List<string> GetStudentInformation()
    {
         List<string> studentInformation = new List<string>();

         //first name
         Console.WriteLine("Enter the student's first name: "));
         studentInformation.Add(Console.ReadLine());

         //last name
         Console.WriteLine("Enter the student's last name: "));
         studentInformation.Add(Console.ReadLine());

         //more
         return studentInformation;
    }

    static void PrintStudentDetails(List<string> studentInformation)
    {
         foreach (string info in studentInformation)
         {
              Console.WriteLine("{0}", info);
         }
    }

    public static void Main (string[] args)
    {
         List<string> studentInformation = GetStudentInformation();
         PrintStudentDetails(studentInformation);
    }
```

or create a class to store all the inputs (better solution):

```
 class Student
    {
        public string FirstName {get;set;}
        public string LastName {get;set;}
    }

static Student GetStudentInformation()
    {
         Student student = new Student();

         //first name
         Console.WriteLine("Enter the student's first name: "));
         student.FirstName = Console.ReadLine();

         //last name
         Console.WriteLine("Enter the student's last name: "));
         student.LastName = Console.ReadLine();

         //more
         return student;
    }

    static void PrintStudentDetails(Student student)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0}", student.FirstName);
        Console.WriteLine("{0}", student.LastName);
    }

    public static void Main (string[] args)
    {
         Student student = GetStudentInformation();
         PrintStudentDetails(student);
    }
```

Comment: the return Console.ReadLine(); needs to be sdtFirstName = Console.ReadLine(); , because I'm trying to get other String var from the user and store it then call on the PrintStudent method to retrieve all the data the student enter. any ideas as how i can do this? thanks

Comment: @user2447032: In case you need to retrieve more than 1 input from the user. You can return a list of strings or create a class to store all the inputs. I'll update the answer

Answer (score 0):

Student.java

```
public class Student {

    private String studentName;

    public Student(String studentName) {
        this.name = studentName;
    }

    public static String getStudentName() {
        return studentName;
    }
    public static void setStudentName(String newName) {
        studentName = newName;
    }
```

Then you could do:

```
Student aStudent = new Student(Console.ReadLine);
```

I understand that this doesn't work EXACTLY for your particular case, but it's only meant to display the basic logic behind what you want to do.